# Connect API site and Get Access Token

Tags: c#, oauth, httpclient

I want to connect API site, and get Access Token(oAuth2).
This site need client id, client secret, code, and redirect URL.
But, now API site said "401"('Unauthorized').
So, please tell how to fix it.

My URL(redirect) is "http://www.localhost/hoge?puyofuga123(puyofuga123 is session, random charset).
My source(C#)

```
const string CLIENT_ID="****CLIENT_ID*****";
const string CLIENT_SECRET="****CLIENT_SECRET*****";
const string CODE = "****CODE****";
string redirectURL = context.Request.Url.ToString(); //HttpListenerContext context
Dictionary<string, string> dicRequest = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"grant_type","authorization_code" },
    {"client_id",CLIENT_ID },
    {"client_secret",CLIENT_SECRET },
    {"code",CODE },
    {"redirect_uri",redirectUrl }
};
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false});
HttpContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dicRequest);
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//Get Access token, but now return 401.
responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("****POST_URL****", httpContent);
```

Comment: "*So, please tell how to fix it.*" without looking at your code too much, this is vender specific and its nearly impossible to help you without reading the documentation, I personally feel OAuth is a mess and every cowboy/girl can implement it the way they want much like most of the web world. What I suggest you do is use postman so you can try things fast, re read the documentation thoroughly and completely, if pain persists see your doctor (I mean, contact the vendor)

Answer (score 0):

To get the tokens in a secure and proper way, you should use the AddOpenIDConnect(...) handler in your startup class, instead of trying to do it your self.

Doing it right and in a secure way is very hard and difficult.